Do switches try to keep track of Ethernet group membership?
I'm trying to better understand ethernet multicast support. My current understanding is that the I/G bit in the destination MAC address indicates whether the target recipient is an individual address or a group address.
For individual addresses, the switch will attempt to forward the frame onto the specific port that is connected to the target host (assuming it's already in the switches MAC table).
For group addresses, the switch will simply broadcast the frame to all hosts. Each host will then determine if it's subscribed to that specific group address. If it's not, it will ignore the frame.
So my question: do switches try to keep track of ethernet group membership in general to avoid unnecessary broadcasts? It sounds like IGMP snooping may be a special case of this. But in general, is it possible for switches to maintain a list of group memberships by port?

Multicast only really exists on the IP network layer, not on Ethernet's data link layer. The latter is all about the I/G bit, the least significant bit in a MAC address's first octet. When that bit is 0 the frame is unicast, when it's 1 the frame is broadcast by Ethernet switches. Individual NICs may filter by group address though.
IGMP snooping works on the network layer, using the destination IP address. When IGMP snooping is active on a switch, the multicast address may limit the general broadcast indicated by the I/G bit to subscribed multicast group members. IGMP membership is tracked, but there is no such thing for MAC.

I'll need to study IGMP it sounds like.
Is it more accurate to say that a "Broadcast" message is actually just a group address "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF" in which all hosts are members. While a "Multicast" message is a group address which only some hosts are members?

Yes, depending on the multicast range, individual host interfaces may subscribe to or unsubscribe from membership.

Hmm, I thought there were separate Ethernet/MAC address ranges for multicast too, 01:00:5e:xx:xx:xx for IPv4 and 33:33:xx:xx:xx:xx for IPv6? Which I suppose means that switches could filter based on those, instead of looking at the whole IP address inside (the packet within) the frame. I don't know what they do in practice.

There are, but they are only relevant for host NICs, not for switches. IGMP snooping may filter by MAC address (less precise) or by IP address (more precise).

@ilkkachu, that would only work if there were a one-to-one ratio between IP and MAC multicast addresses, but it is much more complicated than that. There are 32 IPv4 multicast addresses that resolve to each MAC multicast address, so it would be inefficient to use the MAC multicast addresses to limit the interfaces to which the frames would go. Also, multicast Join and leave messages use IP addressing.

@RonMaupin, if there were a one-to-one ratio or if you accept the collisions / imperfect filtering.


do switches try to keep track of ethernet group membership in general
to avoid unnecessary broadcasts? It sounds like IGMP snooping may be a
special case of this. But in general, is it possible for switches to
maintain a list of group memberships by port?

Switches with IGMP snooping do that, which is why IGMP snooping was created, but other switches without IGMP. or switches with IGMP snooping disabled do not do that. Also, multicasts in the link-local multicast range are not subject to IGMP snooping, per the IETF recommendations in RFC4541, Considerations for Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) and Multicast Listener Discovery (MLD) Snooping Switches:


Packets with a destination IP (DIP) address in the 224.0.0.X range
which are not IGMP must be forwarded on all ports.
This recommendation is based on the fact that many host systems do
not send Join IP multicast addresses in this range before sending
or listening to IP multicast packets.  Furthermore, since the
224.0.0.X address range is defined as link-local (not to be
routed), it seems unnecessary to keep the state for each address
in this range.  Additionally, some routers operate in the
224.0.0.X address range without issuing IGMP Joins, and these
applications would break if the switch were to prune them due to
not having seen a Join Group message from the router.




Yes, when IGMP snooping is enabled, the switch maintains lists of allowed Multicast addresses for each port. The lists are maintained[1] by tracking IGMP group membership join and leave messages. Those lists may be multicast MAC addresses or IP addresses, depending on the complexity of the implementation. Using MAC addresses is more typical as they can be added to the Forwarding Database (FDB) tables of each switchport, and don't require any additional IP protocol awareness. However, for historical reasons, every MAC multicast address actually maps to 32 IPv4 multicast addresses. But that's usually not a problem because the host node itself also has the opportunity to  filter out unwanted traffic.
Otherwise, as you describe in your question, multicast traffic is treated the same as broadcast, and once traffic from a multicast group is routed to a local network, every node will receive the frame, even if they did not request it. This is considered OK because again each host's MAC will filter based on it's own list of accepted destination addresses, which is controlled by the host operating system or similar.
Actually, it's not just multicast traffic that gets treated as broadcast. Most switches treat ALL unknown destination MACs as broadcast. It's just that usually MAC learning kicks in very quickly after powerup.
Some switches support a "filter unknown" behavior, which would, instead of treating multicast or unfamiliar unicast like broadcast, block it. This helps when things get very misconfigured, such as when someone has hardcoded their ARP table with an absent or invalid MAC address, then starts transmitting to it blindly (e.g. if someone makes an entry in /etc/ethers or runs the arp -s command).
[1] The list of addresses allowed to be forwarded to a port can be learned dynamicly via MAC learning, IGMP snooping, via static configuration, or in the case of Time Sensitive Networking switches, via the deterministic Network schedule in YANG format. The FDBs in a TSN network can be deterministically defined via the Centralized User Configuration (CUC) server.

"for historical reasons, every MAC multicast address actually maps to two IPv4 multicast addresses." For mathematical reasons (2^5=32), every MAC multicast address maps to 32 IPv4 multicast addresses. There are 28 bits of IPv4 multicast addressing, but only 23 bits of MAC multicast addressing.

Woah, I do not know why I wrote two instead of 32. I will edit that. Thanks for the correction. I stand by the historical part, though. Xerox PARC didn't want to buy enough OUIs to provide 1 to 1 coverage between IP and MAC, so they had to make do with half of an OUI's worth.
